# How do i extract JSON in Android from this

Tags: android, json, android-json

So this is what i have

`{"REQUEST_TYPE_SENT":"SERVICE_GET_CCAVENUE_KEY","order_id":"1"}`

I want to put `SERVICE_GET_CCAVENUE_KEY` in a String,like wise "1" in a string,how can i achieve this,sorry i'm really noob in programming,i just started out

Edit:-
so if ijust use JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(string),then obj.getString(order_id),would this work to get the order_id number ??

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at the top-voted answer on the linked duplicate. Make a `JSONObject` from that `String`, then use the `get*()` methods on that as needed.

Comment: so if ijust use JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(string),then obj.getString(order_id),would this work??

Comment: Close: `obj.getString("order_id")`.